# Led puff lights making crackling noise

Tags: electrical

Is it normal for my 6 puff lights to make a crackling or popping noise when I turn them off after being on for awhile? Is it safe?

Comment: Usually if you hear popping noise with electric devices, I usually hope it is making pop corn( with butter).

Comment: How loud is the popping noise? If it’s fairly quiet, it might just be a piece of metal cooling off and bending back into its room-temperature shape. I’m not sure there’s ever a reason for an LED to crackle, though…

Comment: some of these leds are so low profile and they do get hot so you can have expansion noises.  if you touch the led in question after you've left it on for a while does it feel hot?

Comment: It's not real loud and of them make that noise only for a second after I lurn them off.

Comment: They are very warm to the touch. Should they be that hot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.